# cannot select columns in a table as one of the column name is limit

Tags: pyspark

```
The above code is resulting in issues as it has a column name as keyword
```

limit. If I remove the column 'limit' from the select list, the script is 
   working fine. 
    Table A has following contents
    \**** Table A *******\\\\

```
There are two tables A , B Table A as follows
 ID    Day      Name  Description  limit  
 1   2016-09-01  Sam   Retail       100
 2   2016-01-28  Chris Retail       200
 3   2016-02-06  ChrisTY Retail      50
 4   2016-02-26  Christa Retail      10
 3   2016-12-06  ChrisTu Retail     200
 4   2016-12-31  Christi Retail     500

Table B has following contents
\\\**** Table B *****\\\\\\\
 Table B

ID SkEY
1  1.1
2  1.2
3  1.3
```

The above code is resulting in issues as it has a column name as keyword
   limit. If I remove the column 'limit' from the select list, the script is 
   working fine.

```
\\\**** Tried Code *****\\\\\\\
 from pyspark.sql import sparksession
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
 from pyspark import HiveContext
 hiveContext= HiveContext(sc)
 ABC2 = spark.sql(
"select * From A where day ='{0}'".format(i[0])
 )
Join = ABC2.join(
 Tab2,
 (
    ABC2.ID == Tab2.ID
)
)\
.select(
Tab2.skey,
ABC2.Day,
ABC2.Name,
ABC2.limit,)
withColumn('newcol1, lit('')),
withColumn('newcol2, lit('A'))
ABC2 .show()
```

ABC=spark.sql(
    "select distinct day from A where day= '2016-01-01' "
    )

```
\\\**** Expected Result *****\\\\\\\
How can we amend the code so that the limit is also selected
```

Comment: did you try removing the comma after `ABC2.limit`?

Comment: yes, its same same issue

Comment: It worked this wasy. not sure why & how but is successful\\\**** Tried Code *****\\\\\\\
 from pyspark.sql import sparksession
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
 from pyspark import HiveContext
 hiveContext= HiveContext(sc)
 ABC2 = spark.sql(
"select Day,Name,Description,limit as liu From A where day ='{0}'".format(i[0])
 )
Join = ABC2.join(
 Tab2,
 (
    ABC2.ID == Tab2.ID
)
)\
.selectexpr(
"skey as skey",
"Day as Day",
"Name as Day",
"liu as limit",)
withColumn('newcol1, lit('')),
withColumn('newcol2, lit('A'))
ABC2 .show()

Answer (score 0):

```
It worked this wasy. not sure functional reason but is successful, Renaming   
the limit as alias before and there after getting it back
\\**** Tried Code *****\\\\\\\ 
from pyspark.sql import sparksession 
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit 
from pyspark import HiveContext 
hiveContext= HiveContext(sc) 
ABC2 = spark.sql( "select Day,Name,Description,limit as liu From A where day
 ='{0}'".format(i[0]) ) 
 Join = ABC2.join( Tab2, ( ABC2.ID == Tab2.ID ) )\ 
.selectexpr( "skey as skey", 
            "Day as Day", 
            "Name as Day", 
            "liu as limit",) 
 withColumn('newcol1, lit('')), 
 withColumn('newcol2, lit('A')) 
 ABC2 .show()
```